# Setting a different search engine for private browsing

Tags: browser, search-engine, private, google-search, duckduckgo

Is there a way to set a different search engine to private browsing mode? e.g. Google for normal mode and duckduckgo when switching to private mode? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [**Turbo Browser**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hawk.android.browser)：

You can switch the search engine easily on the search bar. Whether you want to use `duckduckgo/google` in normal mode or `duckduckgo/google` in privacy mode, it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I should have specified I was looking for a way to do that on a desktop browser. I thought a sort of script to automatically switch from one search engine to another would exist.